# C++ help! Int is stuck and wont move up or down according to user input

Tags: c++

So I'm new to programming, not REALLY new but new enough for me to be posting this. Anyways I've been working on a little text based game project because the best way to learn coding is to just do it, and while I was working I ran into a spot where i needed the user to press space at least once every 2 seconds and if they didn't then the battle number would go down! problem is then they get into the do loop i created they just get stuck at 50 and it never moves up and down. Now I feel like this doesn't take much programming and that it's just a little error I made but I've stared at this for to long and still haven't see anything so please help if you can. I will put the part of the code that I'm talking about below then I will put the whole code after that.

P.S. If you have any other random tips while looking at my code please let me know because as I said I am a beginner.

The piece I'm talking about:

```
        do {

        c = _getch();

        system("cls");
        cout << "Get the number 100!" << endl;
        cout << battleNum << endl;

        if (c == 32) {
            battleNum + 5;
        }

        _sleep(500);

        if (c != 32) {
            battleNum - 1;
        }

    } while (battleNum != 100 && battleNum != 0);
```

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "worldOne.cpp"

using namespace std;

#define SPACEBAR = 32;

void lvlStart();

int main()
 {
    //menu choices
    int menuChoice, settingsChoice, stageChoice, worldChoice;

    //world choices {
    //One
    int lvlSelectOne;
    //Two
    int lvlSelectTwo;
    //Three
    int lvlSelectThree;
    //}

    //level locks
    int oneOne, oneTwo, oneThree, twoOne, twoTwo, twoThree, threeOne,         threeTwo, threeThree;

//world completion out of /10
int worldFin1, worldFin2, worldFin3;

//world locks
int worldTwoM, worldThreeM;

//world visual locks
int worldLock2, worldLock3;

//leveling system
int xp, lvlOnexp, lvlTwoxp, lvlThreexp, lvlFourxp, lvlFivexp;

//combat
int playerHp, battleNum;

playerHp = 100;
battleNum = 50;

worldFin1 = 0;
worldFin2 = 0;
worldFin3 = 0;

worldLock2 = 1;
worldLock3 = 1;

oneOne = 0;
oneTwo = 0;
oneThree = 0;
twoOne = 0;
twoTwo = 0;
twoThree = 0;
threeOne = 0;
threeTwo = 0;
threeThree = 0;

worldTwoM = 0;
worldThreeM = 0;

xp = 0;
lvlOnexp = 0;
lvlTwoxp = 0;
lvlThreexp = 0;
lvlFourxp = 0;
lvlFivexp = 0;

mainMenu:
system("cls");
cout << "WELCOME TO DUNGEON TAP!" << endl;
cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
cout << "1)Play" << endl;
cout << "2)Settings" << endl;
cout << "3)Exit" << endl;
cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << "Type 321 at any time to go back one!" << endl;
cout << "Do not enter a letter, as it will crash the game!" << endl;
cin >> menuChoice;

if (menuChoice == 1)
{
    worldSelect:
    system("cls");
    cout << "UNLOCKED" << endl;
    cout << "|||||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "||   " << worldFin1 << "/10" << "    ||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "|||||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "               " << endl;
    if (worldLock2 == 1)
    {
        cout << "LOCKED" << endl;
    }
    else if (worldLock2 == 2)
    {
        cout << "UNLOCKED" << endl;
    }
    cout << "|||||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "||   " << worldFin1 << "/10" << "    ||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "|||||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "               " << endl;
    if (worldLock3 == 1)
    {
        cout << "LOCKED" << endl;
    }
    else if (worldLock3 == 2)
    {
        cout << "UNLOCKED" << endl;
    }
    cout << "|||||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "||   " << worldFin1 << "/10" << "    ||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "||           ||" << endl;
    cout << "|||||||||||||||" << endl;

    cout << "What world do you want to do?" << endl;
    cin >> worldChoice;
    if (worldChoice == 1)
    {
        goto worldOne;
    }
    else if (worldChoice == 2 && worldTwoM == 1)
    {
        goto worldTwo;
    }
    else if (worldChoice == 2 && worldTwoM == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Sorry you have not unlocked this world yet!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        goto worldSelect;
    }
    else if (worldChoice == 3 && worldThreeM == 1)
    {
        goto worldThree;
    }
    else if (worldChoice == 3 && worldThreeM == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Sorry you have not unlocked this world yet!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        goto worldSelect;
    }
    else if (worldChoice == 321)
    {
        goto mainMenu;
    }
    else if (worldChoice != 1 && worldChoice != 2 && worldChoice != 3 && worldChoice != 321)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "That was not a option, please try again!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        goto worldSelect;
    }


}
else if (menuChoice == 2)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "There are no settings yet!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    goto mainMenu;
}
else if (menuChoice == 3)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Goodbye!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
else if (menuChoice == 321)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "You can not go back from the main menu you silly goose!"<< endl;
    system("pause");
    goto mainMenu;
}
else if (menuChoice != 1 && menuChoice != 2 && menuChoice != 3 && menuChoice != 321)
{
    system("cls");
    cout << "Sorry that was not a choice!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    menuChoice = 0;
    goto mainMenu;
}

worldOne:
    system("cls");
    cout << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << endl;
    cout << "||  " << oneOne << "/3" << "   ||" << "     " << "||  " << oneTwo << "/3" << "   ||" << "     " << "||  " << oneThree <<"/3   ||" << endl;
    cout << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << endl;
    cout << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "What level would you like to do?" << endl;
    cin >> lvlSelectOne;
    if (lvlSelectOne == 1)
    {
        goto lvlOne;
    }
    else if (lvlSelectOne == 2 && oneTwo == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Sorry you have not unlocked this level yet!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        goto worldOne;
    }
    else if (lvlSelectOne == 2 && oneTwo == 1)
    {
        goto lvlTwo;
    }
    else if (lvlSelectOne == 3 && oneThree == 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Sorry you have not unlocked this level yet!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        goto worldOne;
    }
    else if (lvlSelectOne == 3 && oneThree == 1)
    {
        goto lvlThree;
    }
    else if (lvlSelectOne == 321)
    {
        goto mainMenu;
    }
    else if (lvlSelectOne != 1 && lvlSelectOne != 2 && lvlSelectOne != 3 && lvlSelectOne != 321)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Sorry that was not a option!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        goto worldOne;
    };

worldTwo:
    system("cls");
    cout << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << endl;
    cout << "||  " << twoOne << "/3" << "   ||" << "     " << "||  " << twoTwo << "/3" << "   ||" << "     " << "||  " << twoThree << "/3   ||" << endl;
    cout << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << endl;
    cout << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "What level would you like to do?" << endl;
    cin >> lvlSelectTwo;

worldThree:
    system("cls");
    cout << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << endl;
    cout << "||  " << threeOne << "/3" << "   ||" << "     " << "||  " << threeTwo << "/3" << "   ||" << "     " << "||  " << threeThree << "/3   ||" << endl;
    cout << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << "     " << "||        ||" << endl;
    cout << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << "     " << "||||||||||||" << endl;
    cout << "What level would you like to do?" << endl;
    cin >> lvlSelectThree;


    //level one
lvlOne:
    int c = 0;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Welcome to level one!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    int healthO;
    lvlStart();
    cout << "Get the number to 100!" << endl;
    do {

        c = _getch();

        system("cls");
        cout << "Get the number 100!" << endl;
        cout << battleNum << endl;

        if (c == 32) {
            battleNum + 5;
        }

        _sleep(500);

        if (c != 32) {
            battleNum - 1;
        }

    } while (battleNum != 100 && battleNum != 0);




    //level two
lvlTwo:
    system("cls");
    cout << "Welcome to level two!" << endl;
    system("pause");

    //level three
lvlThree:
    system("cls");
    cout << "Welcome to level three!" << endl;
    system("pause");
}

void lvlStart()
{
system("cls");
cout << "Ready..." << endl;
_sleep (1000);
system("cls");
cout << "Set..." << endl;
_sleep(1000);
system("cls");
cout << "GO!!!" << endl;
_sleep(1000);
system("cls");
}
```

Comment: You should add a minimal, complete and verifiable example instead of posting your entire source.

Comment: 1) Do not add unrelated tags! 2) TL;DR 3) [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main issue**

The expression `battleNum + 5` doesn't modify `battleNum` and so a statement consisting of just that is meaningless. What you really want to write is:

```
battleNum = battleNum + 5;
```

... which can be written even more simply as:

```
battleNum += 5;
```

This will assign the result of that expression to the original variable.

**Additional tips**

Since you requested additional tips/criticisms, here are some other issues with your code:

1. Using `_getch`. The underscore prefix is typically an indication that a function is for internal use, only (e.g. in the implementation of some other function). The actual, standardized function is [getch()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/getch.html), which you should be using, instead. That being said, `getch` is part of the curses library, and is thus not as prevalent or common as the more standard C function [getchar()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getchar.html). Since you are using C++, it would make even more sense to use [std::getline()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) or equivalent for your input.
2. Calls to `system` and to `sleep` are additional code smells. When you invoke the `system` command, you are causing a shell interpreter to be instantiated and for it to execute additional code which ultimately ends up invoking  a standard C function that does the same behavior. Just calling the standard C function directly would be more efficient and would also be safer / more portable, because calling a C function will give you an error at compile-time or link-time if it does not exist, whereas `system` calls will produce errors at runtime (if the shell command is incorrect or if the given command does not exist). Additionally, excessive uses of `system()` can lead to security issues (e.g. if you pass unescaped input directly to the shell interpreter). Sleep calls should be replaced with appropriate calls that issue blocking reads on inputs.
3. You include the old, deprecated <conio.h> library. This library is specific to Windows and cannot be found on most newer systems. Your code is very unlikely to be portable by using it.
4. Instead of <stdio.h> you should use <cstdio>; in C++, all the standard C headers have an equivalent header beginning with "c" and with the "h" removed. These headers are generally preferable when including those files from a C++ program.
5. You `#include` a *.cpp source file. Doing this can lead to violations of the "one definition rule" (ODR). You should never, ever include  *.cpp file. Only include *.h or *.hpp files, which merely declare rather than define the contents that are defined in the corresponding *.cpp file.
6. Your constant definition `#define SPACEBAR = 32` incorrectly blends the syntax of macros and the syntax of C++ constants. In C++, it is generally better to use a constant as in `constexpr int SPACEBAR = 32;` or `const int SPACEBAR = 32;` (or, also acceptable, but a little more esoteric, `enum { SPACEBAR = 32; };`). If you do use a macro, it would look like `#define SPACEBAR 32`, however there are significant drawbacks to using macros, and it is generally wise to avoid the macro variant unless the constant must be expressed using that form.
7. You use a significant number of `goto` statements. These are generally a code smell and can also lead to very dangerous errors in other code (for example, [gotofail](https://gotofail.com/)). Almost every usage of goto can be replaced with a function call or subroutine. For example, in your code, you can create a function for each case, define an enum representing the different states, and use a map, return value, or output parameter to specify the transitions between states in your game. See also [goto considered harmful](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).

Comment: Strictily speaking `battleNum + 5` is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: @Olaf, yes, that is correct, it is an expression (hence "the expression battleNum + 5" in my description). But, for the sake of communicating that a line ending in a semicolon is meaningless if it consists of only a non-side-effecting expression, it is useful to describe it as a statement.

Comment: Well, it is not necessarily useless per-se. Actually a null-statement is usefull/required for empty loops. Anyway, I think I think you have a point. Reading on, I think, however, talking about "more (or less) standard functions" might be missleading. `(_)getch` is just non-standard (ncurses is not part of the C standard). Not sure about `getline` though. Is that part of the C++ stdlib? It definitively is not part of the C standard, though.

Comment: I really think the request for a code-review (allthough wrapped in nicer words) makes the question off-topic actually.

Comment: @Olaf curses isn't part of the standard library, but the function is "standard" both in the sense that it is the actual API and not an internal function and in that curses is standardized at the OS level (it is not standardized in the programming language, but it can be found on the vast majority of UNIX systems). And, yes, "getline" is part of the C++ iostream library.

Comment: It might be commonly available, but not standard (assuming you mean `getch` here). Maybe you have a false friend: "standard" vs. "norm"? (It in fact is in my native language). Most target architectures actually do not have (n)curses available. Usage of `conio.h` is a good hint OP is not working on a Unix system actually. FYI: I asked about `getline` because someone used that in C code here, thinking it was C standard.